# adding a string with spaces as an element to array

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading and extracting some filenames from a directory and trying to add them into an array. The given directory has duplicate files so I would be extracting some duplicate file names also.
Original file names in the directory as:

```
100_abc strategy-42005_04May2020_0000-04May2020_first_file.csv   
100_abc strategy-42005_04May2020_0000-04May2020_second_file.csv   
101_xyz statitics strategy_04May2020_first_file.csv
```

Script used:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0

for filename in /home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing/*; do
        #stripping a file name 
        GroupName=$(basename "$filename" ".csv" | awk -F "_" '{print $2}' | awk -F "-" '{print $1}')
        echo "$GroupName"

        var=["$c"]="$GroupName"
        c=$(($c+1))
done
echo "print my array"
echo "${var[*]}"
```

the file name it extracts from directory contains spaces with them. for example.

```
abc strategy
abc strategy
xyz statistics strategy
```

so when I print my array it would be printing like as

```
abc strategy abc strategy xyz statistics strategy
```

above code is adding same file name again to array if it encounter same file again while reading.

so I have added a if statement in order to prevent that, which is not working as expected. I was expecting that array should have unique file name as an element only.

```
for filename in /home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing/*; do
        GroupName=$(basename "$filename" ".csv" | awk -F "_" '{print $2}' | awk -F "-" '{print $1}')

        if [[  "${var[@]}"  =~ "$GroupName" ]]; then
                echo "I am here "
                c=$(($c+1))
                var["$c"]="$GroupName"
        fi

done
```

Comment: What do you mean with "duplicate filenames"? You cannot have two different files with the same name in a directory.

Comment: I mean files are unique with time and date format but while extracting the file names they are meant to be duplicate.

Comment: Could you possibly show us the original filenames?

Comment: have added the file names as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to `sort` in a pipeline:

```bsh
readarray -t var < <(
    cd "$HOME/testing"
    printf "%s\n" * | cut -d"_" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1 | sort -u
)
```

`readarray` will slurp the lines of stdin into the array.

You can inspect the array with `declare -p var`